# Disable to swipe cell in tableView if condition is false in swift?

Tags: swift, swipe, uitableview

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    if condition == true {
    let pause = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "pause") { action, index in
            print("pause button tapped")
            return [pause]
        }
    } else {

        return .None
    }
}
```

> This code didn't disable to swipe in cell. But when swipe the cell delete option appear. Please anyone can help to slove this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550291/disable-cell-swipe-action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`canEditRowAt`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614900-tableview) for that and return `Bool` value according to your condition.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    if condition == true {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

No need check condition in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method.